# How do I change user permissions of a document when I deleted my own permissions as owner?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, permissions, administration, groups

I am the owner of a SharePoint site. I wanted to prevent users downloading a particular document, so I changed the user permissions to 'restricted view'.

I changed the user permissions for visitors, members, and by accident also for owners, myself.

Now I cannot delete or manage this document any longer. How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Site collection administrators of SharePoint site will have access to all the documents in SharePoint site, even if you have unique permissions on documents.

[image]

So, you can connect with either Site collection administrators of this particular SharePoint site OR SharePoint administrator of whole tenant and request them to grant full control access on this document.